# Spotinst plugin exited before we could connect on terraform

Tags: terraform, spot-instances

I wanted to run our terraform code for a small change today. But I started to get this error: `provider.spotinst: plugin exited before we could connect` plugin exited before we could connect` We use this terraform code for a long time. And our version for Spotinst is defined like that:

```
version = "< 1.0"
```

This is the plugin that we use: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/spotinst/spotinst/latest/docs
I couldn't understand why we started to get this error. Does someone have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the actual code you have?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are no available releases matching the given constraints ( < 1.0 )

please change to `>= 1.0` and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there is one plugin for this version. Otherwise, terraform returns with an error that says `no suitable version installed` I was using that plugin as it is till this month. 
I cannot use your suggestion because I need the older version due to some legacy usage.

Comment: I believe that is the question to the plugin repository owner. You can however build your own provider from older tag and set it up locally, using these directions: https://github.com/spotinst/terraform-provider-spotinst#building-the-provider

Comment: Or I have to upgrade it somehow. If I can find migration documentation for this error, I will do it. Maybe I can come up with an answer. `Provider doesn't support resource: spotinst_aws_group` Because of this error, I cannot upgrade the plugin. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I believe you need to remove that object from state with `terraform state rm` and change the code of `spotinst_aws_group` into `spotinst_elastigroup_aws` but I don't know if you can import resources with spotinst provider